# Glitches on after some code is uploaded

Tags: apex, metadata-api, aura, upload, illuminatedcloud

I use WebStrom + Illuminated Cloud 2 to upload code to my **sandboxes**.

1. Sometimes I'm **uploading** some component and apex classes, and in my log view confirms that my code was completely uploaded. example (Deployment Complete: Deployed 2/2 components to devship2 in 6s 555ms with status COMPLETED.)
   But then I go to setup / Developer Console on website, and view the codes I just uploaded, and some of my **code/methods are missing!** Very randomly!
2. All code **changes don't take effect** right away, I have to refresh my org multiple times, until I see my code changes. (I console.log my code version to be sure the latest is loaded)

Am I the only one experiencing this?

Is there something I'm doing wrong in process of uploading code?

Comment: Might get better responses if you reach out to the support staff for Illuminated Cloud.

Comment: To address #2, you should benefit from disabling the client-side cache in the sandbox. This will keep you from having to refresh multiple times to see changes in the org. **Setup > Security > Session Settings > Cache > uncheck Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance.** [Lightning Components Performance Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/lightning-components-performance-best-practices.html#settings)

Comment: You've answered the second part, I wish you posted it as an answer. Thanks a lot!